# Difference Between : and = with javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript codes which look same each other.

The first one is like below resulting 2, 101, 102 in a row.

```
<script>
    var val = 100;
    var counter = {
        val : 1,
        func1 : function() {
            this.val += 1;
            alert('func1() this.val: ' + this.val);
            func2 = function() {
                this.val += 1;
                alert('func2() this.val: ' + this.val);
                func3 = function() {
                    this.val += 1;
                    alert('func3() this.val: ' + this.val);
                };
                func3();
            };
            func2();
        }
    };
    counter.func1();
</script>
```

The following code is the second one. The Result is 2,3,4

```
<script>
    var val = 100;
    var counter = function() {
        val = 1;
        func1 = function() {
            this.val += 1;
            alert('func1() this.val: ' + this.val);
            func2 = function() {
                this.val += 1;
                alert('func2() this.val: ' + this.val);
                func3 = function() {
                    this.val += 1;
                    alert('func3() this.val: ' + this.val); 
                };
                func3();
            };
            func2();
        };
        func1();
    };
    counter();
</script>
```

Q.Just in my opinion, this difference comes from the marks : =. Is that right?

Q.Technically, is this difference related to Lexial Environment?

Q.Are those two marks supposed to have difference scope or closure ?

Q.If the above questions are not the reason, then what could be the reason?

Comment: You use `:` to assign property or variable in an object. And `=` to assign them in non-object.

Comment: have you heard about `scope` in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You should try strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, `var val = 100;`defines a the variable as global with a value of `100`.
`val : 1,` defines a property named `val` inside the `counter` object.

In the second snippet, `val = 1;` defines the assignment of the value `1` of the global varaible `val`.

So it is normal, that the result is different: it's a question about `variable scope`.